# Scrapy shell does not open

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

I have a conda virtual environment called scrape where I have scrapy installed. But whenever I type in the command `scrapy shell` I get the following error.

`$ scrapy shell Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 6, in <module> from scrapy.cmdline import execute File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module> from scrapy.spiders import Spider File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 11, in <module> from scrapy.http import Request File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module> from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 16, in <module> from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\response.py", line 14, in <module> from twisted.web import http File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 183, in <module> from twisted.web._http2 import H2Connection File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_http2.py", line 27, in <module> import h2.connection File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\h2\connection.py", line 23, in <module> from .events import ( File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\h2\events.py", line 14, in <module> from .settings import ChangedSetting, _setting_code_from_int File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\h2\settings.py", line 25, in <module> class SettingCodes(enum.IntEnum): File "C:\Users\Ravi\anaconda3\envs\scrape\lib\site-packages\h2\settings.py", line 60, in SettingCodes ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL = SettingsFrame.ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL AttributeError: type object 'SettingsFrame' has no attribute 'ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:
The problem was that Scrapy was either using an older version of h2 or not using one at all. `pip install --upgrade h2` fixed it.